# Why MySQL database replica does not replicate when replica has bigint key and master has int key?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-replication, mysql-8.0

I try to change the primary key size or another field from int to bigint.

MySQL manual tells me that this type of convert is available (from int to bigint), but my replica gets an error:

```
Column 1 of table 'Items' cannot be converted from type 'int' to type 'bigint(20)'
```

As example master table

```sql
create table Items(
 id int auto_increment,
 quantity int null
)
```

Replica table

```sql
create table Items(
 id int auto_increment,
 quantity bigint(20) null
)
```

MySQL version 8.0.15

Why MySQL broke replication when replica has type bigint over int on master?

Comment: I tried this case on my database without AWS RDS. Same result.

Comment: that depends on the slave_type_conversions  mode you have.

Comment: There is a way to make this work, but is should very rarely be needed.  Why does the replica not match the master exactly?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot to perform DDL without downtime. 1) I make replica as writable 2) Perform migration 3) Propagate replica to master (this is aws rds feature)

Comment: Yes, that's a valid case.  Be sure to allow the replica to catch up before promotion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Problem with config field `slave_type_conversions`

By default, MySQL has empty `slave_type_conversions` this means that all columns in the source and target tables must be of the same types.

I changed this value to `ALL_LOSSY,ALL_NON_LOSSY` and MySQL allowed conversion to bigint

Comment: You should probably avoid `ALL_LOSSY` since it's... lossy... and allows typically nonsensical things like replicating an `INT` into a `TINYINT` with consequent loss of data, unless you happen to have an (e.g.) `INT` column with no values that would overflow a `TINYINT`.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-features-differing-tables.html#replication-features-attribute-promotion